# Python function which will call a 1D vector values

Tags: python, arrays, function, scipy, interpolation

I have the next sequence of numbers of A array( is an array 1D )

1. -1.7654142212e-06
2. 7.0737426918e-07
3. 1.63230254789e-06
4. 1.88255344022e-06
5. 5.00966829007e-06
6. 1.88631278169e-06
7. -4.08751917695e-06
8. 9.12971786351e-07
9. 5.33615185204e-06
10. -1.01338496378e-05

are 100 values, just say that are only 10.

I need a function that will call these numbers.

EDIT

using x, x= np.linspace(0,1000,10)

I used scipy.interpolate.interp1d and its not working so good...

EDIT

the interpolation take the first and last value, and do an aproximation.
In my case the values are too small, and accuracy is important. 
Also, A values are changing on each x step, enough to cause an error after few iterations.

So if our array is

A = ((-1.7654142212e-06 , ....,-1.01338496378e-05 ))`

I need a function to work like that:

EDIT

e.a. A_FUNCTION(0) = -1.7654142212e-06 ....

to call any value I want, without call the approximation of the value, (for a specific #number of x) inside another function on the main or a second script.

Comment: You want to do interpolation.  Regarding `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`: what does *its not working so good* mean?  Show the code you tried, and the complete error messages that you got or explain how it did not work as you expected.

Comment: I need this array to be a function, cause I use it as argument in a function that it is called by another function in another script.

When I try to use it in this format inside the function:
e.a print(K[1])
I get the error:
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I am trying more than one month to solve this issue and is not an easy one. My code has 2 scripts. A Array has 100 values, parameter of a function. The second script need the A array values, which iss being calculated in the first script. On the main script function I have A as a argument. The function is a equation like that u'-Au-5=0
This is a system of 100 equation, which each equation has a specific A value! When the second script function call this function, 100 times, I need to have the analogue value of A each time. Only making A function I manage to do that, but is not working.

Comment: @user1640255 well your question did not ask for that. So you need to re-edit your question to be more clear because all you asked for was some way to get an item from a list, which `my_list[number]` will do.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just create a function that takes two inputs: an array, and number

```
In [15]: A
Out[15]: 
array([-4611686018427387904, -4611686018427387904,                    7,
                          0, -4611686018427387904,  5764616295532855496,
       -4611686018427387899, -4611686018427387904,                    4,
           1407374883553280])

In [16]: def grab_item(array,number):
   ....:     return array[number]
   ....: 

In [17]: grab_item(A,8)
Out[17]: 4
```

After the multitude of comments, here is an example of what I believe you want through using this function:

```
In [24]: x = np.linspace(0,1000,100)

In [25]: grab_item(x,9)
Out[25]: 90.909090909090907
```

Comment: I cant do that, I tried this:
A_f = grab_item(A, x)
which x = np.linspace(0,1000,100)

ERROR
arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Comment: why can't you do that? you really are not being clear as to what you need?

Comment: cause inside the function I need instead of "8" to have x[line] , which line is a number from 0-99

Comment: so if x is the array and line is the number. In this function just do `grab_item(x,line)` how does that not work?

Comment: ERROR: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Comment: why is x not assigned before you run the function...x only doesn't exist if you don't create x...

Comment: sure thing, take your time. And if it's helpful, I've added an example that uses x so you can see what I mean

Comment: YOU ARE GREAT!!!! it is working!!! this is amazing! more than one month trying to fix that... 

The interpolation issue :

A[0] : -1.7651598078827736e-06 -1.76515980788e-06

A[1] : -1.7647417510993283e-06 7.07272329683e-07

A[2] :-1.7643236016843e-06 1.63206731726e-06

A[3] :-1.7639053596749269e-06 1.882282146e-06

...

the right value is the result of the scipy interp1d of (x, A),and the other value of the real data of A on each gridpoint

the interpolation do some kind of fitting.I cant understand. x is a linspace of 100 values, as the A. it should have the same values.
nevermind
THANK YOU

Comment: awesome!! if this worked you should mark it as the correct solution by clicking the check